# PHP with oracle bangla font not support

Tags: php, oracle, fonts, utf

Oracle with PHP bangla font not support.

I trited with `$conn = oci_connect("ABDMS", "LANKA", "150.180.3.140:1521/aisdb",'AL32UTF8');`

But not working. its showing `????????? ?????`

Without AL32UTF8 , showing `��������� �  ..`

page meta is `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

I'm running it on Xammp.

Is any one any idea ??

Answer (score 0):

[image]

> AL32UTF8 character support versions are

- 9i - 10g
- Oracle9i Database Release 1: 3.0
- Oracle9i Database Release 2: 3.1
- Oracle Database 10g, Release 1: 3.2
- Oracle Database 10g, Release 2: 4.0

Please check your oracle version.

```
// code 
set NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8
```

Comment: Can you please tell me any other encoding system for oracla Bengali support..  my version Oracle 10g

Comment: If you are using window flat from run the code

`set NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8` 
hope it will worke

Comment: I'm trying to connect remote database. Where i set NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8  . Please elaborate.

Comment: Just open data base editor where you can run query. Select database and run the code on editor  `NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8`

For example: if you are using Toad for oracle then use it's editor and select db where you want to run the code.

Comment: i am a bit busy in my office right now, i will must be reply you later on.

Comment: You can try it on 11g for Windows flat from 
`set NLS_LANG= AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252`